# npm start runs my updated code, but docker runs with a outdated code

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, npm, docker-compose

Yeah it's confuse a lot, when i start my application with npm start like normally do, it starts fine and i can see my chances and updates but when i create a docker-compose file and a dockerfile and runs into a docker container, it runs a very outdated version of my code.

I  tried everything to fix this issue, i can't understand where does docker gets this outdated code that doesn't even exist in my machine or in the project. i cleaned cache also, i removed all images / containers but still the same thing

the question is, where docker finds this code and why does it finds and why does docker run this code that doesn't even exist in my local machine or my code? why can't he run my code like npm start do?

i can't find the issue with it

Here the docker file and docker compose file for a simple local run

```
FROM node:12.18.4 as build

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app/package.json
COPY package-lock.json /app/package-lock.json
RUN npm ci
RUN npm i react-toastify

COPY . /app
RUN rm .env
COPY .env.production .env
RUN npm run build

# production environment
FROM nginx:1.17.9-alpine
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
COPY nginx/decode.crt /etc/nginx/decode.crt
COPY nginx/decodewp.key /etc/nginx/decodewp.key

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

--------------------------------------------------

version: "3.6"
services:
    decode.up4biz.frontend:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "4000:80"
            - "4001:443"
        restart: always
        stdin_open: true
        volumes:
           - './:/app'
           - '/app/node_modules'
        environment:
          - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
```

Comment: The Dockerfile is compiling the application into static files and serving it via Nginx.  Do you need to re-run `docker-compose build`?

Comment: i did run docker-compose build / docker-compose up --build but nothing changes

Comment: those nginx things are envs for production

Comment: and no i don't need to re run docker-compose build @DavidMaze

Comment: To answer your question about where the container get the code from, it gets it from /usr/share/nginx/html where you copy it to and where nginx serves it from.

Comment: that might be the cause, i'm going to test this and going to give you a feedback about it

Comment: @HansKilian that line should copy my build / code, that should contain my updated code not my old one. i'm very confused with it

Comment: @HansKilian the worst thing is that this outdated code doesn't exist, this line should get my correct build / code. i can't understand

Comment: Do `docker-compose build` to make sure you have the newest code in your image. As for getting hot reload to work, that'll take some major changes since your Dockerfile is making a deployable image that contains the code. Hot reload requires that the code is on the host computer and not inside the image, so 'deployable' and 'hot reload' don't mix well.

Comment: i've run a ``docker-compose build`` but still not updating my code there, intresting that my updated code works when i run ``npm start``

Comment: @HansKilian i think there's a problem into my ``npm run build`` i guess that might be the problem, the build is not getting my updated changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found something, there was a issues into my docker file, i've created each file for each different environments and changed the nginx configuration.
I thought it was just a build issues but it wasn't, it was just the nginx with docker not talking with each other well
Here's my dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
ARG ENV
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app/package.json
COPY package-lock.json /app/package-lock.json
RUN apk --no-cache add npm
RUN npm install --package-lock
RUN npm i react-toastify
COPY .env.development .env
RUN npm run build-development
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx/nginx-development.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

And here my nginx configuration that fixed the issue:

```
 location / {
    root /app/build;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

what fixed the problem was this line here

```
root /app/build;
```